# Reiniciar servidor Django Python

Tags: python, django

Olá! Estou iniciando no mundo da programação, através de um livro chamado "Curso Intensivo de Python". Um dos projetos do livro envolve a criação de um ambiente virtual para utilizar o Django. Consegui configurar tudo corretamente (as partes que eram diferentes do que estava no livro, achei a resposta na internet) e iniciei o servidor. Nesse projeto é criado um pequeno banco de dados (através do SQLite) e alguns cadastros foram feitos.

Tudo ia bem até que o servidor que eu havia iniciado pelo Windows PowerShell caiu. O comando que utilizei para startar o servidor foi: python manage.py runserver. Esse arquivo manage.py fica na raiz do projeto e está tudo ok.

O único problema é que depois de um tempo sem fazer algum processo na outra janela do PowerShell (onde digito os comandos), o servidor ficou offline, o que obviamente também derrubou o acesso ao localhost:8000 (eu já esperava esse comportamento). Meu ambiente virtual no Django se chama ll_env. Então usei o comando ll_env\Scripts\activate para acessar o ambiente virtual e depois tentei reiniciar o servidor com o comando anterior (python manage.py runserver) mas não funciona. É como se o arquivo manage.py não fosse mais reconhecido e Shell retorna o erro abaixo.

Alguém sabe por favor, como faço pra reiniciar o servidor ou ainda se há alguma configuração para que o servidor não caia?

> Watching for file changes with StatReloader
> Exception in thread django-main-thread:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()
> File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
> self._target(*self.*args, **self.*kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\marlo\PycharmProjects\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
> fn(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\marlo\PycharmProjects\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
> autoreload.raise_last_exception()
> File "C:\Users\marlo\PycharmProjects\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
> raise *exception[1]
> File "C:\Users\marlo\PycharmProjects\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init**.py", line 357, in execute
> autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
> File "C:\Users\marlo\PycharmProjects\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
> fn(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\marlo\PycharmProjects\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django_*init**.py", line 24, in setup
> apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
> File "C:\Users\marlo\PycharmProjects\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
> app_config.import_models()
> File "C:\Users\marlo\PycharmProjects\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
> self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
> File "C:\Python38\lib\importlib_*init**.py", line 127, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
> File "", line 783, in exec_module
> File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
> File "C:\Users\marlo\PycharmProjects\learning_log\learning_logs\models.py", line 16, in 
> class Entry(models.Model):
> File "C:\Users\marlo\PycharmProjects\learning_log\learning_logs\models.py", line 18, in Entry
> topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

Answer (score 0):

`"TypeError: init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'"`

isso significa que na linha 18 do seu arquivo **models.py** está faltando um argumento `*on_delete*` que faz referência a uma chave estrangeira

provavelmente vc tem algo assim:

```
class AlgumModelo(model.Model):
    
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
```

e vc precisa acrescentar o **'on_delete'**

```
class AlgumModelo(model.Model):
    
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

vc pode usar outras funções, uma delas pro *on_delete* é `on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING`

corrigindo esse problema, vc consegue reiniciar o servidor

Comment: Show!! Deu certo! Usei o on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING. De fato não tinha isso no arquivo models.py. Vou aproveitar pra me aprofundar nos estudos dessa parte relacionada ao banco de dados. Muito obrigado :)

Comment: antes de se aprofundar em qlqr coisa, vc precisa aprender a entender a lógica das mensagens de erro. Normalmente está escrito o que vc precisa fazer, ou dá uma pista do que pode estar causando. Provavelmente quem te negativou a pergunta, acha que vc não se esforçou direito pra entender o erro, mas tmb não veio te falar isso. Paciência. Não desista